# Logfile Class error "You cannot execute this operation since the object has not been created."

Tags: smo

We wanted to automate few management operations for new SQL Server installation, so we started looking into 
[LogFile Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.logfile.aspx)
But this class doesn't let us run  the ALTER() method to change log file location. Also doesn't let us add a new file and drop and existing file. Anyone know the internals of this class :) ?

NOTE: I know we can run a SQL query and run ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE and copy files and restart db. This question is specific to this class.

I also tried to alter an existing file instead of creating a new one and dropping existing one , and it throws the same error.

ERROR 
"{"Drop failed for LogFile 'DBAUtility_log'. "}"

{"You cannot execute this operation since the object has not been created."}

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server srv = new Server("xx");
            Database db = default(Database);
            db = srv.Databases["DBAUtility"];
            //LogFile LF = new LogFile(srv.Databases.ItemById(0),'DBAUtility_log');
            //Console.WriteLine("DB:", srv.Databases.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(srv.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("DBName" + srv.Databases.ItemById(5).ToString());


            LogFile lf = new LogFile();

            Console.WriteLine("LF:" + lf.ToString());
            lf.Parent = db;

            lf.Name = "DBAUtility_NEWLOG";
            lf.FileName = "M:\\DBFiles\\SQLlog\\1\\DBAUtility_1.ldf";
            lf.Create();
            LogFile lf2 = new LogFile();

            lf2.Parent = db;
            lf2.Name = "DBAUtility_log";
            lf2.FileName = "C:\\Install\\DBAUtility_1.ldf";
            lf2.Drop(); //ERROR HERE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create a log file for this database

```
$LogFileName = $db.name + '_Log'
$LogFile = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.LogFile') ($db, $LogFileName)
$db.LogFiles.Add($LogFile)
$LogFile.FileName = $LogFileName + '.ldf'
$LogFile.Size = $logfilesize * 1024
$LogFile.GrowthType = 'KB'
$LogFile.Growth = $logfilegrowth * 1024
$LogFile.MaxSize = -1
$db.Create()
```